# Attempting to verify an underflow exception but cannot get the exception to occur

Tags: c, floating-point, arm, iar

I am doing an arithmetic operation on a `double` type.  However, while initializing the double I cannot get an underflow error or exception.  Maybe it is related to my compiler settings...

I am using IAR Embedded Workbench and my platform is an ARM966E-S.  My code is as follows:

```
#define DOUBLE_POS_MAX    1.79769313486231570814527423732E308
 #define DOUBLE_POS_MIN   2.22507385850720088902458687609E-308

double float_nan_var;

float_nan_var =   DOUBLE_POS_MIN / DOUBLE_POS_MAX ;
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What is the definition of `DOUBLE_POS_MIN`?

Comment: Can you provide the specific part number for the microcontroller that you are using?

Comment: @embedded_guy device no is ST STR912FAx46

Comment: The code shown does not attempt to catch the exception.  Please post the code the sets up the exception handler and handler itself.

Comment: @chux if the compiler perform the above mention division it should raise an under flow. why to write an handler.

Comment: @user2262711 The handler may quietly handle the underflow by returning `0.0` and code proceeds as normal.  We do not know a handler was not called, just that it did not result in the desire exception.  By linking in your own handler, (or other means), we may find out if the handler was called.  If an underflow raises a visible exception or quietly handles it is often a run-time configurable option: see `fetestexcept()`.  I cannot speak for ARM though.